# Using VPNs and getting "The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed."

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, role-base-authorization

We are developing for a client that requires us to be on their VPN to access their database resources rather than ours.  We are using Windows to get the primary identity of which we only care about the username to be our key going forward:

```
 services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
```

Then we add our own table driven identities that contain roles:

```
//...Get the user name from AD.
var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity;
string domainName = "";
string userName = claimsIdentity.Name;
if (claimsIdentity.Name.Contains("\\"))
{
  domainName = claimsIdentity.Name.Split("\\")[0];
  userName = claimsIdentity.Name.Split("\\")[1];
}
//...Use the userName in the database to get the primary roles.....
ourIdentityClaims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userInfo.Roles.First().Name));
//...Add our custom identity with the claims.
principal.AddIdentity(new ClaimsIdentity(ourIdentityClaims, "OurIdentity"));
```

Then we Authorize the controller (or whatever):

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "Technician")]
//...or just...
    [Authorize]
    public class WhateverController : Controller
```

Pretty standard stuff in terms of role based authentication.

If we run this while on OUR vpn (not the client and using mock data) then all is well.  But when we go on the client's vpn and drop off of ours we get "The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed."

Of course this makes perfect sense because our PCs are registered to a domain that does not match the VPN we're currently on.  So all the other suggestions you see out there about removing and adding to the domain don't really apply here.  We also recognize that once the client uses the application on their PCs on their VPN all will be fine.  So this is really just a development issue in a world where we're all on VPNs!

How can I get around this issue?  Keep in mind that I do not care about anything in Windows AD other than the person's UserName.  I don't care about AD groups or any of that.  We handle ALL of the role management ourselves with local tables and custom identities added to the principal user in a ClaimsLoader.  But we do need the user name.

I have plenty of ideas but they're all pretty extensive.  I'm curious if there is a simple way to code some development environment marked code to say..."Yeah yeah...We're not on the normal domain....We don't care."

Comment: if it is for developing, looks like you can update your connection string (dedicated for development only) to not use trusted connection. So that means a login info is required (so just create a login just for development as well).

Comment: So the problem isn't with the database connection -- we are actually using a SQL Login for database connectivity.  While on their VPN we can get to their database via IP address and credentials in the conn string.  The problem is when we add the [Authorize] attribute to a controller and bring up a page it triggers some sort of communication with IIS/AD that notices the current user is not on a trusted network with the same domain as my user:  MYCOMPANY\kfizz instead of THEIRCOMPANY\jsmith.

If we're on MYCOMPANY VPN [authorize] works, but then we have ZERO access to their SQL server by IP.

Comment: it sounds like there is some hidden windows authentication enabled here. That kind of authentication should be disabled if not used on purpose.

Comment: you can find out more about configuring Windows authentication here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/windowsauth?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio  I think your error is caused by some Windows authentication process. If you don't mean to use Windows authentication then it should be disabled.

Comment: We do need windows authentication.  The issue is we're not on the same domain when we VPN.  I have read that article before but I'll look again.  Thanks.

Comment: yes disabling Windows authentication when developing is easier than trying to connect your networks into one same trusted network/domain.

Answer (score 0):

Another similar but different question allowed me to stumble on the answer.  Apparently just by copying the principal to a new principal in my ClaimsTransformation detaches it from whatever it was doing on a future role check.

It doesn't make complete sense, but it's working....

OLD CODE:

```
        public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
        {
            \\....My code to build myClaims.

            principal.AddIdentity(new ClaimsIdentity(myClaims, "MyNewIdentity"));
            return await Task.FromResult(principal);
         }
```

NEW CODE:

```
        public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
        {
            \\....My code to build myClaims.

            var newPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(principal);
            newPrincipal.AddIdentity(new ClaimsIdentity(myClaims, "MyNewIdentity"));
            return await Task.FromResult(newPrincipal);
         }
```